# org.jbehave.core.steps.Steps$DuplicateCandidateFound: THEN the result will be $expected

Tags: java, jbehave

I have below jbehave story file:

```
Scenario: Scene1
Given the number of <input>
When the result is estimated
Then the result will be <expected>

Examples:
|input|expected|
|1|1|
|2|1, 2|
|3|1, 2, 3|
|4|1, 2, 3, 4|

Scenario: Scene2
Given the number of <input>
When the result is estimated
And the result is sorted in descending order
Then the result will be <expected>

Examples:
|input|expected|
|1|1|
|2|2, 1|
|3|3, 2, 1|
|4|4, 3, 2, 1|
```

Now I wanted to test both the scenarios in my program, so I have written below code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.List;

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;

public class EstimatorSteps {
    private Estimator estimator;

    @Given("the number of $input")
    public void given(int input) {
        estimator = new Estimator(input);
    }

    @When("the result is estimated")
    public void when1() {
        estimator.estimate(estimator.getInput());
    }

    @Then("the result will be $expected)
    public void then1(List<Integer> result) {
        assertEquals(estimator.getResult(), result);
    }

    @When("the result is sorted in descending order")
    public void when2() {
        estimator.descending(estimator.getResult());
    }

    @Then("the result will be $expected)
    public void then1(List<Integer> result) {
        assertEquals(estimator.getResult(), result);
    }
}
```

When I run the test case, I get below error message:

> org.jbehave.core.steps.Steps$DuplicateCandidateFound: THEN the result
>   will be $expected

What is the right way to test both the cases, what changes I have to do in my Java code. I do not want to change my story file.

Here is my JBehave configuration file:

```
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.io.CodeLocations;
import org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath;
import org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.jbehave.core.io.CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass;
import static org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder.Format.CONSOLE;

public class JBehaveStories extends JUnitStories {

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration().useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                        .withCodeLocation(codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass())).withFormats(CONSOLE));
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new EstimatorSteps());
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()),
                Arrays.asList("**/*.story"), Arrays.asList(""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two identical @Then steps in `EstimatorSteps` class:

```
@Then("the result will be $expected)
public void then1(List<Integer> result) {
    assertEquals(estimator.getResult(), result);
}

....

@Then("the result will be $expected)
public void then1(List<Integer> result) {
    assertEquals(estimator.getResult(), result);
}
```

and JBehave complains:

```
DuplicateCandidateFound: THEN the result will be $expected
```

---

Remove one of these method and the error will not appear.

BTW I wonder how did this class compile at all, since Java shouldn't allow for two overloaded methods with exactly the same signature.

Comment: Both methods are missing an end quote as well.  I am also curious as to how this even compiles.